# Multiple 3D Objects in .FBX - How to apply a different texture to each one

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am developing an AR app and I am importing a FBX file having two 3d objects inside (I cannot have two separated fbx files because the objects interact each other with an animation).

We would like to apply texture1 to object1 and texture2 to object2.

The problem is that the .sfb, from my experience, is seen as a unique model and when I apply a texture, at runtime it is applied to both object1 and object2.
Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance

```
val builder = ModelRenderable.builder()
builder.setSource(activity, Uri.parse(arModelli.uri))
renderableFutureAmo = builder.build()
renderableFutureAmo.thenAcceptBoth(materialFuture) { renderableResult, materialResult ->
    renderableModelAmo = renderableResult
    customMaterial = materialResult

    renderableModelAmo!!.setMaterial(1, customMaterial.value) // in this way I can apply the texture only to one 3d object, but the other one?
    customMaterial.switchBaseColor()
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting the texture in a 3D editor and exporting your fbx as an obj?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement ontap listner i.e.

1. transferable.setontaplistner(listner);
2. get node from hittestresult
3. then set texture on that node